# how to create a ioncube license.txt file for a project

Tags: encoding, license

I am using ioncube php encode for my project. Please let me know how to create a license file and load to the encode.I have tried with the below command. After encoding the project is not loading.

```
 ./ioncube_encoder55 /var/www/html/emc -o /var/www/html/emcnew --with-license /var/www/html/emcnew/license.txt --passphrase sample
```

Please  help me to fix the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make_license --pass sample -o license.txt

Note the example license above has no restrictions.  Copy to the emcnew directory. It's generally better to encode with just the file name for the license file and not a full path and locate in or above the web root directory. Contact ionCube support for more details.

Comment: I need to create a license for my product with one year validation. Please guide me with the command. after one year,If I change the license.txt file .. the license of the product should allow the product to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
./make_license --pass sample -o license.txt --expire-in 365d
```

Used above command to create a license file and copied the license.txt to the core directory.

```
./ioncube_encoder55 /var/www/html/emc -o /var/www/html/emclic --with-license license.txt --pass something
```

Finally encoded with above command.